# DraggableScrollableSheetのAdaptiveについて

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

Regarding the Adaptive feature of DraggableScrollableSheet, the issue is that due to differences in the device's devicePixelRatio, the display appears as follows:
I've thought about it a lot, but I couldn't come up with the right solution.
How can I accurately ensure that it is displayed at the same size?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKlRB.png)
[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7osSr.png)
[image]

full code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        _DraggableSheet(),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class _DraggableSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      initialChildSize: 0.2,
      minChildSize: 0.1,
      maxChildSize: 0.3,
      expand: true,
      snap: true,
      snapSizes: const [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
      builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: ListView.builder(
              controller: scrollController,
              itemCount: colorfulContainerList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => colorfulContainerList[index]),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

final colorfulContainerList = [
  Container(
    height: 25,
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
  Container(
    height: 20,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
  Container(
    height: 20,
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
  Container(
    height: 20,
    color: Colors.yellow,
  ),
  Container(
    height: 20,
    color: Colors.grey,
  ),
  Container(
    height: 20,
    color: Colors.brown,
  ),
  Container(
    height: 20,
    color: Colors.pink,
  ),
  Container(
    height: 20,
    color: Colors.purpleAccent,
  ),
  Container(
    height: 20,
    color: Colors.teal,
  ),
];
```